# Get IP Address of pc from android device programmatically

Tags: android, ip

I have connected my PC wired to the router, whereas my android device is wirelessly connected to the same router.

I need to access the  nodejs server running on my machine from my app. I need to retrieve IP Address of the machine in Android app.

I have tried this code

```
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    String ip =  Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
    return ip;
```

ipconfig commands displays 192.168.1.100, whereas in code its returns 192.168.1.103 ....How do I make it get the IP Address of the machine in my app?

Comment: `I have connected my PC to wired Ethernet network`. Do you mean that you connected your PC wired to your router? `whereas I am sharing PC network with android device through hotspot.`. Do you mean that you connected your Android device wireless to the same router?

Comment: `I need to get the IP Address of my PC in Android studio.`. For what does Android Studio need an ip adress? I would think that your Android app on your device would like to know the ip of your PC.

Comment: `But my network settings displays 192.168.1.100`. Those are the network settings of your PC? Where do you see that?

Comment: yeah exactly, that is what i meant!!

Comment: `whereas in code its returns 192.168.1.103`. If that code runs on your Android device than that is the ip of your Android device.

Comment: `yeah exactly, that is what i meant!! `. Well then edit your post and make a good story first.

Comment: actually i need to access localhost in my app.

Comment: For your app running on your Android device localhost is the Android device itself. Every device is it's own localhost.

Comment: i am running a nodejs server on my pc

Comment: Very nice. Now if you would rephrase your problem...

Comment: `need to access the localhost running on my machine`. Do you mean you want to access the nodejs server running on your pc?

Comment: `IP Address of the machine in Android studio.`. You were already told that that is not in Android studio.

Comment: yup to access nodejs server

Comment: Your app has no idea of course what your pc would be. Not even has the router. The router could tell your app which ips are `reachable`. Which ones are in use. And one of those ips could be the ip of your pc. Google for isreachable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any app will either (1) allow the user to manually type a hostname or IP address of the server it needs to reach, or (2) a hostname will be hardcoded into the app.

Since you are operating on your own LAN, a hostname won't do, as no DNS server will resolve it.

So (1) will be the easiest route for you. Of course, you could store the IP so that you don't need to type it every time.

And your pc would need to have a static IP, instead of a dynamic (DHCP) IP. You can assign for example 192.168.1.99 as your DHCP range seems to start at 100. Make sure you also fill in the default gateway, and at least one DNS server. Type "ipconfig /all" (if it's a Windows pc) to find out the current values.

If your code does not need to be flexible, you could even hardcode that IP 192.168.1.99 into your app, so that you don't need to enter it.

(There are ways to scan the network for pc's that listen on a certain port, but these are not so easy to program, moreover, if more than one machine on your network would be running nodejs server, you would have no clue which one your app should access.)

Answer (score 1):

See my gist [here](https://gist.github.com/raizal/67f7a03f9a4b46e1dbe3)

I use it for my old project.

Answer (score 1):

This **worked** for me:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

Don't for get to give **ACCESS_WIFI_STATE** and other permissions in the **manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```